# React testing function calls with Jest and Sinon not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, sinon, jestjs

I'm trying to assert the number of times my React class method is called after an event. I have tried using sinon.spy and jest.fn() to no avail.

Using sinon.spy:

```
test('Some test', (done) => {
  const page = renderLookupPage();
  const formInputButton = page.find('.button').first();
  formInputButton.simulate('click');

  let spy = sinon.spy(page.instance().myReactMethod);

  const button = page.find('.tag').first();
  button.simulate('click');

  setTimeout(() => {
        try {
            console.log(spy.callCount); //0
          done();
        } catch (error) {
          done.fail(error);
        }
      }, 100);
    });
```

with jest.fn():

```
test('Some test', (done) => {
  const page = renderLookupPage();
  const formInputButton = page.find('.button').first();
  formInputButton.simulate('click');

  page.instance().myReactMethod = jest.fn(() => {});

  const button = page.find('.tag').first();
  button.simulate('click');

      setTimeout(() => {
        try {
            console.log(page.instance().myReactMethod.mock.calls.length); //0
          done();
        } catch (error) {
          done.fail(error);
        }
      }, 100);
    });
```

I have assurance the method in question is definitely being called. What is more confusing is a console.log statement in the method prints before the

> console.log(spy.callCount)

Any pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple,

I moved the line

> page.instance().myReactMethod = jest.fn(() => {});

above the previous line:

> formInputButton.simulate('click');

Not sure why this worked, and it would be great to hear from someone as to why this affected the result?

**NOTE: formInputButton doesnt call the function in question**